# Trunking on HP ProCurve 2610 Switch

Tags: ethernet, switch

I have a network of computers for which I would like to divide into the appropriate VLANs and configuring trunking with an ADSL modem. I'm using a series of HP ProCurve 2610 switches which is directly hooked up to an ADSL modem. However my networking skills aren't mature yet and the software that HP uses is giving me a hard time? I'm currently studying for my CCNA exam and I still lack the necessary experience to get myself out of this jam and I'm also unfamiliar with HP switch configuration. I'm currently studying for my CCNA exam and basically understand how it can be done on Cisco switches (theoretical).

I know people should buy only switches they are familiar with, but my employer had already bought those.

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: I want to set up the VLANs and get trunking to work towards the ADSL port.

Comment: What does that mean? Presumably your ADSL modem doesn't support any trunking (I haven't seen one that does), so what would that do?

Comment: Tagging = Trunking in HP terms.  They are almost identical other than terminology.